# Inheritance of Segues in Objective C/iOS app development

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a custom MyUITableViewController, that I have a segue when user select one of the rows to another ViewController that shows the details of about the item in that row.  (I build using Storyboard, and Segue Identifier, "foobar").

I created another ChildTableViewControler which inherits from MyUITableViewController. Since the items displayed in it is the same, I just have a different set of items, I would like the behavior of the select item to be the same. So i.e. when user select one of the rows, I want it to perform the same segue. So I would assume I don't have to write the segue code again.

However, when I run the app and click one of rows in the ChildTableViewController, it says the segue with identifier "foobar" is not found, and crashes.

So there is no inheritence in segue? I have to write segue code repeatly?

Comment: Does the segue you create from ChildTableViewController have the same segue identifier "foobar"?

Comment: No, there is no inheritance of the segue itself. A segue is unique to a particular instance of a controller in your storyboard. However, that doesn't mean that you need to write the prepareForSegue code repeatedly -- that should be inherited.

Comment: I didn't create a segue specifically for ChildTableViewController. I was hoping that the segue identifier "Foobar" I created for the parent would be inherited by the child. Apparently not. So how do I create a segue identifier dynamically? For example, for the ChildTableViewController, I don't want to use storyboard, because I want to create it and display it dynamically as needed.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make sense. If you're not using storyboards, then you can't have a segue -- the whole idea of segues is to give you a visual representation of a transition between controllers that you can see in the storyboard. If you're not using a storyboard, then you should just present or push your controller in code.

Comment: The parenttableviewcontroller is created using storyboard. For the childtableviewcontroller (because I plan to have many different childtableviewcontrollers, all different sets of same type of items) I don't plan to have a different story board for each of these childtableviewcontrollers, and was planning to create them dynamically as needed. I just want all of them to have the same behavior: click on one row, it segues to another itemdetailsviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

As this question remains open, here goes an answer:

The first important thing to mention is that the segue is not a ViewController property, if you go to the UIViewController class and search for segue, you will find only methods and no property, which already is a sign that it can't be inherited. Then if you check the UIStoryboardSegue interface you will find this:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) __kindof UIViewController *sourceViewController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) __kindof UIViewController *destinationViewController;
```

In the [UIStoryboardSegue documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html) you will find:

> A UIStoryboardSegue object is responsible for performing the visual
>   transition between two view controllers. In addition, segue objects
>   are used to prepare for the transition from one view controller to
>   another. Segue objects contain information about the view controllers
>   involved in a transition The UIStoryboardSegue class supports the
>   standard visual transitions available in UIKit. You can also subclass
>   to define custom transitions between the view controllers in your
>   storyboard file.

The segue is responsible only for the visual transition between viewControllers and that **the segue holds** information about the specific viewControllers involved in this transition, also meaning that the segue is specifically about those view controller, as it references to them.